# Get All Nearby Events From Facebook In Windows Store App

Tags: c#, facebook, events, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've been searching on this matter for a while but it seems I only get results which do not match my case.

Is it possible that via de Facebook API for Windows Store apps, we could get all the events in a specific location?

Is it mandatory to be logged with a Facebook account? Because I have found several posts of gettings the events of your friends, but I'd want to get all the events (even those that friends might not attend to, but in your specific location).

Is this achievable at all?

So far I haven't found anything good, so if you could point me to any useful links, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try using FQL ?

Comment: I didn't use FQL before, but I'm trying to figure a way on how ths would be achieavable. Basically, I'm asking if people could point me to existing resources, give suggestions or short code samples to outline how the approach would look like.

Comment: Using FQL, that may be simple ... I'm at work so I cant provide you references (dont have access to FB developpers), but this would look like "select evtid from events where -your condition-".
There is an FB app (which i dont remember the name) which allows you to type FQL directly in FB: Very usefull to test your requests!

Comment: I'm open to all kind of ideas, cause so far the results of my efforts to create something were close to zero. But please make sure it's compatible with Windows Store API.

Comment: Since the `location` field in the evnets table in non-indexable; you can not use this in the FQL's WHERE clause. `Search` API may be useful to you (I'm not sure), just like what's mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181480/how-can-i-query-public-facebook-events-by-location-city