# Facebook Graph API Event Search Not Working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This question "how to search facebook public events using graph api" has already been asked and successfully answered.

[How can I query public facebook events by location/city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181480/how-can-i-query-public-facebook-events-by-location-city)

All examples look ok and they match facebook search api docs but some reason non of them are functional

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dlondon%26type%3Devent&version=v2.5

Any ideas what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something does not work as expected, it´s most likely because of a bug. Right now it´s a well known bug and subject of many bug reports already: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/916199865137566/

Comment: Thanks for reply. This idea visited me, but still wanted to double check myself.