# How do I fetch the facebook events of a particular location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to fetch all the facebook events by passing a latitude or longitude or a place, As FQL support is no more, I've tried the following query

```
search?q=*&type=events&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000
```

But the results I get are from syria, India, USA, Hungary and all, why I'm not getting the events from only that location I've specified. Is there any legal issues in fetching the public events from facebook, How many number of eevnns I can fetch at a time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly search for events in a specific area. The `center` and `distance` parameters are only available for Places, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

More information:

- https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201749749651827
- [How can I query public facebook events by location/city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181480/how-can-i-query-public-facebook-events-by-location-city)

About "how many events can i fetch", those are the API rate limits: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

API results usually have a limit of 25 entries for one API call. But you can set it higher:

```
/search?type=event&q=test&limit=100
```

Legal issues depend on what you want to do with the data, impossible to say without knowing the details for your App.

Comment: what about the legal issues on accessing the events

Comment: "how many events can i fetch" is not a legal issue, it´s a matter of api limits. i will include something about that in my answer.

Comment: No no... my question is... whether I would face any legal issues if I fetch public events from facebook using its api.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the events, of course. if you just want to show public events somewhere without showing attending users or even storing them, there should be no problem

Comment: it is always a problem when you want to show user data and the user did not authorize your app to show up somewhere else. users should always be in full control about what info there is about them and where exactly.

Comment: do you have any link to their privacy policy, so that I can understand every details related to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101982/discussion-between-fazeela-abu-zohra-and-luschn).

Comment: that´s general privacy rules (and common sense), not just for facebook ;)

Comment: but for a specific answer, you would have to explain what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I have a page to list events, where I'll show every data about eg., event name, description, who all are attending etc. For every user these data will be same, so my question if a user A(is registered to my app), user B(not registered) are attending an event E, then can I include user B as he is not registered to my app.

Comment: that´s a grey area. i would say if he did not authorize your app, you should not show them elsewhere (basis privacy rule, don´t show anything from a user elsewhere without his authorization)